# Using locks on Akka Actors

Tags: scala, locking, akka

I have a Actor that goes like this (assume that the receive method is overridden somewhere else):

```
class MyClass extends Actor {     
  def method1() = { ... }

  def method2() = { ... }

  def method3() = {     
    this.synchronized {
      ....
      ....
    }
  }
}
```

What happens if I have a final field defined in my Actor as:

```
private val lockType = new AnyRef
```

I then can use this lock to synchronize my method3? What would be the difference? My understanding is that using this reference to lock on a method would make that reference unavailable until the lock is released.

In the above case, I use a lock that can function independently of the this reference and lock only when some action on method3 is made, while the this reference is still available for the other threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for synchronization inside of an actor. The actor will only ever process a single message at a time.

Comment: What if the method3 executes in a Future?

Comment: If you execute something in a Future, send the result as a message to the actor.